# Fourier Series involving modulus function

Tags: calculus, functions, fourier-series

I've come across this problem as stated:

Let $f(x)$ be the function $f(x) = |x| + \pi$, if $-\pi < x < \pi$.

Find the exact values of the first two non-zero terms of the Fourier Series for $f(x)$.

I understand that it is an even function given that $f(-x) = |-x| + \pi = |x| + \pi = f(x)$, thus $b_n = 0$ for all $n=1,2,3...$

However, as I got stuck and referred to suggested solution, in the steps the $\pi$ was omitted from $f(x)$, leaving only $f(x) = |x|$ in the sense that when finding $a_0$, the solution took $|x|$ as $f(x)$ instead of $|x| + \pi$.

Why was the solution presented this way?

Thank you.

Comment: It is generally a good idea to use MathJax/LaTeX formatting on this site. I've made those changes for you, pending approval. Great first question, and it shows you've made your own effort, too! Welcome!

Comment: @TheCount Thank you for making the changes for me! I'll try my best to learn how to use the MathJax formatting properly in due time so others have an easier time reading my question(s) in future (hopefully I won't have to ask too many times here though...)!

Comment: @stepchia Ask lots of questions! It helps everyone. And it takes a few minutes but is eventually quite intuitive. If you are unsure how to do something, google "(thing you want to do) Latex" and you will surely find what you need. all the best!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If $n\neq 0$, note that
$$
\int_{-\pi}^\pi \cos(nx)~dx = 0.
$$
The Fourier cosine coefficients are:
$$
\frac{1}{\pi}\int_{-\pi}^\pi f(x)\cos(nx)~dx = \frac{1}{\pi}\int_{-\pi}^\pi |x|\cos(nx)~dx + \frac{1}{\pi}\int_{-\pi}^\pi \pi\cos(nx)~dx.
$$
If $n\neq 0$, then the second integral on the RHS is zero, so
$$
\frac{1}{\pi}\int_{-\pi}^\pi f(x)\cos(nx)~dx = \frac{1}{\pi}\int_{-\pi}^\pi |x|\cos(nx)~dx.
$$
The only time we see the $\pi$ is therefore when $n=0$ and $\cos(nx) \equiv 1$.

Comment: Hi Gyu Eun, thanks for the succinct explanation, that makes it very clear to me!